# Программа не верно считает количество слов в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, анализ-данных, nlp, nltk

Заметил две проблемы:

1. В выводе у меня появилось слово  wa, хотя в тесте его нет.
2. Количество слов подсчитывается не верно.

**File**(В котором я вел подсчёт слов): https://dropmefiles.com/qAfrA
**Code**(В расширении .ipynb): https://dropmefiles.com/JV0Y5

```
book = open('book.txt', encoding="utf8").read()
#  Broke the text into word
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
list_text = word_tokenize(book)

# lemmatisation words + lower register
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatized_output = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w).lower() for word in list_text]

en_stopwords = ["a","about","above","after","again","against","ain","all","am","an","and","any","are","aren","aren't","as","at","be","because","been","before","being","below","between","both","but","by","can","couldn","couldn't","d","did","didn","didn't","do","does","doesn","doesn't","doing","don","don't","down","during","each","few","for","from","further","had","hadn","hadn't","has","hasn","hasn't","have","haven","haven't","having","he","her","here","hers","herself","him","himself","his","how","i","if","in","into","is","isn","isn't","it","it's","its","itself","just","ll","m","ma","me","mightn","mightn't","more","most","mustn","mustn't","my","myself","needn","needn't","no","nor","not","now","o","of","off","on","once","only","or","other","our","ours","ourselves","out","over","own","re","s","same","shan","shan't","she","she's","should","should've","shouldn","shouldn't","so","some","such","t","than","that","that'll","the","their","theirs","them","themselves","then","there","these","they","this","those","through","to","too","under","until","up","ve","very","was","wasn","wasn't","we","were","weren","weren't","what","when","where","which","while","who","whom","why","will","with","won","won't","wouldn","wouldn't","y","you","you'd","you'll","you're","you've","your","yours","yourself","yourselves","could","he'd","he'll","he's","here's","how's","i'd","i'll","i'm","i've","let's","ought","she'd","she'll","that's","there's","they'd","they'll","they're","they've","we'd","we'll","we're","we've","what's","when's","where's","who's","why's","would","able","abst","accordance","according","accordingly","across","act","actually","added","adj","affected","affecting","affects","afterwards","ah","almost","alone","along","already","also","although","always","among","amongst","announce","another","anybody","anyhow","anymore","anyone","anything","anyway","anyways","anywhere","apparently","approximately","arent","arise","around","aside","ask","asking","auth","available","away","awfully","b","back","became","become","becomes","becoming","beforehand","begin","beginning","beginnings","begins","behind","believe","beside","besides","beyond","biol","brief","briefly","c","ca","came","cannot","can't","cause","causes","certain","certainly","co","com","come","comes","contain","containing","contains","couldnt","date","different","done","downwards","due","e","ed","edu","effect","eg","eight","eighty","either","else","elsewhere","end","ending","enough","especially","et","etc","even","ever","every","everybody","everyone","everything","everywhere","ex","except","f","far","ff","fifth","first","five","fix","followed","following","follows","former","formerly","forth","found","four","furthermore","g","gave","get","gets","getting","give","given","gives","giving","go","goes","gone","got","gotten","h","happens","hardly","hed","hence","hereafter","hereby","herein","heres","hereupon","hes","hi","hid","hither","home","howbeit","however","hundred","id","ie","im","immediate","immediately","importance","important","inc","indeed","index","information","instead","invention","inward","itd","it'll","j","k","keep","keeps","kept","kg","km","know","known","knows","l","largely","last","lately","later","latter","latterly","least","less","lest","let","lets","like","liked","likely","line","little","'ll","look","looking","looks","ltd","made","mainly","make","makes","many","may","maybe","mean","means","meantime","meanwhile","merely","mg","might","million","miss","ml","moreover","mostly","mr","mrs","much","mug","must","n","na","name","namely","nay","nd","near","nearly","necessarily","necessary","need","needs","neither","never","nevertheless","new","next","nine","ninety","nobody","non","none","nonetheless","noone","normally","nos","noted","nothing","nowhere","obtain","obtained","obviously","often","oh","ok","okay","old","omitted","one","ones","onto","ord","others","otherwise","outside","overall","owing","p","page","pages","part","particular","particularly","past","per","perhaps","placed","please","plus","poorly","possible","possibly","potentially","pp","predominantly","present","previously","primarily","probably","promptly","proud","provides","put","q","que","quickly","quite","qv","r","ran","rather","rd","readily","really","recent","recently","ref","refs","regarding","regardless","regards","related","relatively","research","respectively","resulted","resulting","results","right","run","said","saw","say","saying","says","sec","section","see","seeing","seem","seemed","seeming","seems","seen","self","selves","sent","seven","several","shall","shed","shes","show","showed","shown","showns","shows","significant","significantly","similar","similarly","since","six","slightly","somebody","somehow","someone","somethan","something","sometime","sometimes","somewhat","somewhere","soon","sorry","specifically","specified","specify","specifying","still","stop","strongly","sub","substantially","successfully","sufficiently","suggest","sup","sure","take","taken","taking","tell","tends","th","thank","thanks","thanx","thats","that've","thence","thereafter","thereby","thered","therefore","therein","there'll","thereof","therere","theres","thereto","thereupon","there've","theyd","theyre","think","thou","though","thoughh","thousand","throug","throughout","thru","thus","til","tip","together","took","toward","towards","tried","tries","truly","try","trying","ts","twice","two","u","un","unfortunately","unless","unlike","unlikely","unto","upon","ups","us","use","used","useful","usefully","usefulness","uses","using","usually","v","value","various","'ve","via","viz","vol","vols","vs","w","want","wants","wasnt","way","wed","welcome","went","werent","whatever","what'll","whats","whence","whenever","whereafter","whereas","whereby","wherein","wheres","whereupon","wherever","whether","whim","whither","whod","whoever","whole","who'll","whomever","whos","whose","widely","willing","wish","within","without","wont","words","world","wouldnt","www","x","yes","yet","youd","youre","z","zero","a's","ain't","allow","allows","apart","appear","appreciate","appropriate","associated","best","better","c'mon","c's","cant","changes","clearly","concerning","consequently","consider","considering","corresponding","course","currently","definitely","described","despite","entirely","exactly","example","going","greetings","hello","help","hopefully","ignored","inasmuch","indicate","indicated","indicates","inner","insofar","it'd","keep","keeps","novel","presumably","reasonably","second","secondly","sensible","serious","seriously","sure","t's","third","thorough","thoroughly","three","well","wonder","a", "about", "above", "above", "across", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all", "almost", "alone", "along", "already", "also","although","always","am","among", "amongst", "amoungst", "amount", "an", "and", "another", "any","anyhow","anyone","anything","anyway", "anywhere", "are", "around", "as", "at", "back","be","became", "because","become","becomes", "becoming", "been", "before", "beforehand", "behind", "being", "below", "beside", "besides", "between", "beyond", "bill", "both", "bottom","but", "by", "call", "can", "cannot", "cant", "co", "con", "could", "couldnt", "cry", "de", "describe", "detail", "do", "done", "down", "due", "during", "each", "eg", "eight", "either", "eleven","else", "elsewhere", "empty", "enough", "etc", "even", "ever", "every", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "except", "few", "fifteen", "fify", "fill", "find", "fire", "first", "five", "for", "former", "formerly", "forty", "found", "four", "from", "front", "full", "further", "get", "give", "go", "had", "has", "hasnt", "have", "he", "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein", "hereupon", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "however", "hundred", "ie", "if", "in", "inc", "indeed", "interest", "into", "is", "it", "its", "itself", "keep", "last", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "ltd", "made", "many", "may", "me", "meanwhile", "might", "mill", "mine", "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "move", "much", "must", "my", "myself", "name", "namely", "neither", "never", "nevertheless", "next", "nine", "no", "nobody", "none", "noone", "nor", "not", "nothing", "now", "nowhere", "of", "off", "often", "on", "once", "one", "only", "onto", "or", "other", "others", "otherwise", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own","part", "per", "perhaps", "please", "put", "rather", "re", "same", "see", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", "serious", "several", "she", "should", "show", "side", "since", "sincere", "six", "sixty", "so", "some", "somehow", "someone", "something", "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhere", "still", "such", "system", "take", "ten", "than", "that", "the", "their", "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby", "therefore", "therein", "thereupon", "these", "they", "thickv", "thin", "third", "this", "those", "though", "three", "through", "throughout", "thru", "thus", "to", "together", "too", "top", "toward", "towards", "twelve", "twenty", "two", "un", "under", "until", "up", "upon", "us", "very", "via", "was", "we", "well", "were", "what", "whatever", "when", "whence", "whenever", "where", "whereafter", "whereas", "whereby", "wherein", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether", "which", "while", "whither", "who", "whoever", "whole", "whom", "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without", "would", "yet", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves", "the","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",'co','op','research-articl', 'pagecount','cit','ibid','les','le','au','que','est','pas','vol','el','los','pp','u201d','well-b', 'http', 'volumtype', 'par', '0o', '0s', '3a', '3b', '3d', '6b', '6o', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'aj', 'al', 'an', 'ao', 'ap', 'ar', 'av','aw', 'ax', 'ay', 'az', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'ba', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'bi', 'bj', 'bk', 'bl', 'bn', 'bp', 'br', 'bs', 'bt', 'bu', 'bx', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'ci', 'cj', 'cl', 'cm', 'cn', 'cp', 'cq', 'cr', 'cs', 'ct', 'cu', 'cv', 'cx', 'cy', 'cz', 'd2', 'da', 'dc', 'dd', 'de', 'df', 'di', 'dj', 'dk', 'dl', 'do', 'dp', 'dr', 'ds', 'dt', 'du', 'dx', 'dy', 'e2', 'e3', 'ea', 'ec', 'ed', 'ee', 'ef', 'ei', 'ej', 'el', 'em', 'en', 'eo', 'ep', 'eq', 'er', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'ev', 'ex', 'ey', 'f2', 'fa', 'fc', 'ff', 'fi', 'fj', 'fl', 'fn', 'fo', 'fr', 'fs', 'ft', 'fu', 'fy', 'ga', 'ge', 'gi', 'gj', 'gl', 'go', 'gr', 'gs', 'gy', 'h2', 'h3', 'hh', 'hi', 'hj', 'ho', 'hr', 'hs', 'hu', 'hy', 'i', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i6', 'i7', 'i8', 'ia', 'ib', 'ic', 'ie', 'ig', 'ih', 'ii', 'ij', 'il', 'in', 'io', 'ip', 'iq', 'ir', 'iv', 'ix', 'iy', 'iz', 'jj', 'jr', 'js', 'jt', 'ju', 'ke', 'kg', 'kj', 'km', 'ko', 'l2', 'la', 'lb', 'lc', 'lf', 'lj', 'ln', 'lo', 'lr', 'ls', 'lt', 'm2', 'ml', 'mn', 'mo', 'ms', 'mt', 'mu', 'n2', 'nc', 'nd', 'ne', 'ng', 'ni', 'nj', 'nl', 'nn', 'nr', 'ns', 'nt', 'ny', 'oa', 'ob', 'oc', 'od', 'of', 'og', 'oi', 'oj', 'ol', 'om', 'on', 'oo', 'oq', 'or', 'os', 'ot', 'ou', 'ow', 'ox', 'oz', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'pc', 'pd', 'pe', 'pf', 'ph', 'pi', 'pj', 'pk', 'pl', 'pm', 'pn', 'po', 'pq', 'pr', 'ps', 'pt', 'pu', 'py', 'qj', 'qu', 'r2', 'ra', 'rc', 'rd', 'rf', 'rh', 'ri', 'rj', 'rl', 'rm', 'rn', 'ro', 'rq', 'rr', 'rs', 'rt', 'ru', 'rv', 'ry', 's2', 'sa', 'sc', 'sd', 'se', 'sf', 'si', 'sj', 'sl', 'sm', 'sn', 'sp', 'sq', 'sr', 'ss', 'st', 'sy', 'sz', 't1', 't2', 't3', 'tb', 'tc', 'td', 'te', 'tf', 'th', 'ti', 'tj', 'tl', 'tm', 'tn', 'tp', 'tq', 'tr', 'ts', 'tt', 'tv', 'tx', 'ue', 'ui', 'uj', 'uk', 'um', 'un', 'uo', 'ur', 'ut', 'va', 'wa', 'vd', 'wi', 'vj', 'vo', 'wo', 'vq', 'vt', 'vu', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'xf', 'xi', 'xj', 'xk', 'xl', 'xn', 'xo', 'xs', 'xt', 'xv', 'xx', 'y2', 'yj', 'yl', 'yr', 'ys', 'yt', 'zi', 'zz',',', '.', ':', ';', '!', '?','’','’',',','“','”','(',')','{','}','[',']','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','@','#','$','%','ha','*']

# Removed from  list stopwords 
lemmatized_output = filter(lambda i: i not in en_stopwords, lemmatized_output) 

# Сalculate the number of words
from collections import Counter
top = Counter(lemmatized_output).most_common()
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = top, columns = ['num','word'])

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  
    print(df)
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример с минимальными входными данными.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/3heMf - ссылка на фото. Не знаю в чём проблема, поменял stoplist, но все равно не работает , помогите , первая программа, которую сам написал.

Comment: Проблема с несуществующими символами исчезла, но вот вторая осталась ( так и не понял, почему все заработало)

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что параметром lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) должна быть строка. А у вас  что?  Что в переменной w, которую вы используете в качестве параметра?

Comment: Я поменял W на  word (просто опечатка)

Comment: @DarMaster Т.е. вы выставили неработающий код?  Что бы дать нам возможность немного поломать голову. Спасибо, мы справились. Ваша "просто опечатка" существенно влияет на ход выполнения программы.  Поэтому от вас и просят - минимальный воспроизводимый фрагмент программы с минимальным набором данных.  И ожидаемом на нем результатом. Что-бы можно было посмотреть и проверить, где вы еще "просто опечатались".

Comment: Ну так я его уже выставил, сверху ссылка на фото работы программы

Answer (score 2):

немного оптимизировал код и исправил опечатку `w` -> `word`:

```
from string import punctuation

en_stopwords = set(en_stopwords)

lemmatized_output = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.casefold())
                     for word in word_tokenize(book)
                     if word.casefold() not in en_stopwords 
                        and word not in punctuation]

df = pd.DataFrame(Counter(lemmatized_output).most_common(),
                  columns=['word', 'freq'])
```

результат:

```
In [288]: with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 30, 'display.max_columns', None):
     ...:     print(df.head(30))
     ...: 
             word  freq
0              ai   703
1           human   517
2            goal   380
3            life   372
4            time   245
5          future   229
6        computer   221
7    intelligence   214
8          people   213
9         machine   204
10     technology   200
11           year   193
12  consciousness   182
13         figure   172
14          brain   169
15        chapter   162
16         energy   158
17     prometheus   153
18      conscious   148
19       universe   140
20     experience   136
21         matter   132
22          power   128
23       question   125
24              •   121
25       scenario   119
26           feel   116
27         system   114
28           long   114
29        billion   107
```

Comment: Спасибо, но там опять цифры не сходятся ( rк примеру в книге 5066 - the,  а после работы программы их 440)

Comment: @DarMaster, точно! проверку стоп-слов нужно делать для маленького регистра! Исправил ответ...

Comment: Спасибо, хотя все равно не понятно почему не совпадает фактическое число слов( открываю  txt  версию в браузере и нажимаю поиск по странице с пробелом до и  после слова), и то которое рассчитывает программа

Comment: @DarMaster, так вы не найдёте слова перед которыми или после которых стоят знаки препинания (точка, запятая, дефис, etc.)

Comment: аааа, большое спасибо!

Comment: @DarMaster, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)